# Describe why a distribution might be multimodal?

Tags: distributions, multimodality

Suppose that I visualized a distirbution and noticed that it was multimodal. For example, I collected the heights of a bunch of students.

[image]

I notice that the distirbution is multimodal. How would I investigate the cause of this multimodality?

Comment: I'm surprised that so many students have negative height!

Comment: Ha - just an example

Comment: Among many other possibilities, how about half the students are in 6th grade and half in 10th grade?

Comment: You are right Mark. I'd just love to hear some advice on how to approach this.

Comment: I would initially think it would be due to gender. But it could be due to students by grade. My approach would be to graph a stacked histogram.

Comment: A slide rule and microscope are the preferred tools for this sort of work.

Comment: I don't actually understand what that means

Comment: Should I just try all possible reasons and plot them?

Comment: You can't cover all possible reasons,there are too many. But otherwise, yes: think what the reasons might be and plot away.